# Whether a large or a small ball fall faster in the air?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, drag

Given a ball falling under gravity is subjected to air resistance, after performing a differential to the drag equation, I get:

$$g-Z(v^2)/r  = a = v',$$

(where $Z$ is a constant.)

How can I know which ball will travel faster just by the size of a ball given they have the same density? Much obliged if anyone can help me...

Comment: I don't understand your question. What differential equation are you solving? And what is $r$, the radius of the ball? Hint: First solve the steady state situation (terminal velocity)

Comment: @Bernhard  R is the radius of the ball. The terminal velocity of a large ball is larger , but when two balls havnt reached the terminal velocity, what is happening?

Comment: Size isn't everything!   (sorry  :-)  )

Answer (score 3):

So you know the radius of the two balls, call them $r$ for the small ball and $R$ for the bigger ball.

However, like the commenter Bernhard says, the terminal velocity of each ball will be different.

The terminal velocity is:

$$
v_{t}\propto{\sqrt{\frac{m}{\rho}}}
$$

Now you can begin to plug into the equation and you should be able to see that the larger ball will encounter a larger resistance.

Comment: I don't understand why the terminal velocity is what you have written.why the square of the terminal velocity isn't the ratio of the mass and the cross sectional area of the ball?Thank you for your help:)